# Factorizing vector fields near manifolds of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $V: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth vector field containing a smooth $k$-dimensional manifold $M$ (with $1\leq k < n$) of singularities: $V(M)=0$.

Suppose furthermore that at every point $x\in M$, the derivative $D_x V$ has $(n-k)$ nonzero eigenvalues, and thus $T_x\mathbb{R}^n = T_x M  \oplus F_x$, where $\ker D_x V$ coincides with $T_x S$ and $F_x$ denotes some realization of the quotient space $T_x \mathbb{R}^n / T_x M$.

I am interested in knowing when this geometric splitting induces a corresponding factorization of the vector field. Specifically, I would like to know when I can write $V = W_1 X_1 + \cdots + W_{n-k} X_{n-k} := WX$, so that

- $W = (W_1 \,\cdots\, W_{n-k})$, considered as an $n \times (n-k)$ matrix, has full rank and $\text{Im}\,W(x)=F_x$ for each $x \in M$, and
- $X(M) = 0$ and $\ker D_xX = T_x M$ for each $x \in M$.

In other words, $V$ is factored so that $X$ encodes the information about the manifold $M$ and $W$ encodes the information about the transverse fiber bundle.

What are the results in this direction? I imagine that it's impossible to ask for such a factorization for general smooth vector fields, especially globally, but I am interested to hear about obstructions or sub-cases where problems of this type are studied. I am aware of some (local) positive results in the case when $V$ is polynomial in its entries; here, one can explicitly construct such factorizations using division algorithms for local rings. I've also heard folklore that the case $k=n-1$ (i.e. when $X$ is a scalar function) should be somehow easier or more obvious.

Comment: For example, if the normal bundle   is not trivializable this thing is not possible. In particular, if $M$ is non-orientable  then this is not possible.